# Android: How to scale font size for EditText view that sits on top of an template for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, jpeg, pixel

I have implemented custom greeting cards in the Android app, meaning users can add photos and edit texts in the predefined spots on top of different templates of the greeting card. The cards are 1200x2400 pixels (vertical). Similarly, I have implemented banners with the same logic. The only difference is that the size is 10500x3300 pixels (horizontal).

I have 2 activities, first is the edit card/banner, and next is the preview card/banner.
I am struggling with the font sizes though.

After the user selects the photo/s and edits text/s, The custom texts and images are added to the template and merged into a jpeg file. While creating the jpeg, the font size is multiplied by 1/72 to convert it into per inch.

In Cards, when I use font size 14, it is normally visible text on edit and preview pages. But if I use font size 14 for the banner, the text appears normal on the edit page but very tiny in the preview. Of course, that is because the banner is much larger in size than the cards. So 14 turned into inches is a very small value so tiny text size.

So for banners, I need to use a font size of around 114 for them to appear normal. (These numbers are not constants but font sizes are somewhat closer.)
But on the edit page, text size 114 appears to be huge. So much that even a single letter outgrows the textview.
So that means I need a scaling factor.
I tried to use the below formula to scale the font size:

```
new font = og font x screen width / image width

new font: font size for edit screen.

og font: font size that it actually should be for the text to be accurate size in the preview.

image width: banner or card width;
```

*But it does not work for all screen sizes.*
Ex., in phones, mostly, it works. but for tablets, the text size on the edit page is smaller than it appears on the phone screen. Phone resolution: 1080x2340 (OnePlus 6T), 720x1280 (Galaxy J7) Tablet resolution: 800x1280.
I wonder if the screen aspect ratio makes a difference and if so, why does my formula not work since it does take screen width into account?

I know that the font size is related to the height and not the width. But when I try to change the width to height in the above formula, I still get huge text sizes.
So my question is: how do I set the font size for the banners on the edit page?

A few images attached below are the Edit page and preview page of the Card and Banner:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tkVdMS4Kfaf9AfAY94lLnjxpWhIf2LCI

Comment: I also tried setting DIP and SP in textView.setTextSize(). Does not make much of a difference.